# Defining _Dcomplex externally in Cython

Tags: python, windows, cython, complex-numbers

In a package that I am a developer of we are making extensive use of Cython for performing heavy calculations involving complex numbers. This package needs to be buildable from Unix + Windows systems so we need a way to (re)-define the `double complex` type with compatibility for both (assuming we are using MSVC for compilation of Cython extensions on Windows). Windows does not support `double complex` from C99 but instead defines its own type `_Dcomplex` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/complex-math-support?view=vs-2019).

Due to this differing type, one cannot extern from `<complex.h>` in this way (for example) in a `.pyx` file:

```
cdef extern from "complex.h" nogil:
    double cabs(double complex z)
    double carg(double complex z)
    double complex cexp(double complex z)
    double complex conj(double complex z)
    double cimag(double complex z)
    double creal(double complex z)
    double complex csqrt(double complex z)
```

When trying to compile the resulting `.c` file for the extension (using MSVC) this is contained within, you would get errors such as the following:

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__pyx_t_double_complex'
```

which comes from this block in the `.c` file:

```
#if CYTHON_CCOMPLEX
  #ifdef __cplusplus
    typedef ::std::complex< double > __pyx_t_double_complex;
  #else
    typedef double _Complex __pyx_t_double_complex;
  #endif
#else
    typedef struct { double real, imag; } __pyx_t_double_complex;
#endif
```

I thought I could fix this with the following:

```
IF UNAME_SYSNAME == "Windows":
    cdef extern from "complex.h" nogil:
        double cabs(_Dcomplex z)
        double carg(_Dcomplex z)
        _Dcomplex cexp(_Dcomplex z)
        _Dcomplex conj(_Dcomplex z)
        double cimag(_Dcomplex z)
        double creal(_Dcomplex z)
        _Dcomplex csqrt(_Dcomplex z)
ELSE:
    cdef extern from "complex.h" nogil:
        double cabs(double complex z)
        double carg(double complex z)
        double complex cexp(double complex z)
        double complex conj(double complex z)
        double cimag(double complex z)
        double creal(double complex z)
        double complex csqrt(double complex z)
```

But this just results in the following error when compiling the Cython file:

```
'_Dcomplex' is not a type identifier
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this? Or suggestions for alternatives to MSVC so that we can keep our nice `double complex` based interface as it is (note that all packaging will be done via Conda so there might be such an alternative which I'm not aware of)?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option is to roll these function out, whitout trying to wrap the VC's functionality - sad, but this is the state right now on Windows.

But if you insist on using `<complex.h>` on Windows, this is the best I was able to come up with:

First problem: including  `<complex.h>` on Windows leads to a wrong `CYTHON_CCOMPLEX`-value, and thus the resulting C-file cannot be compiled out-of-the-box, here is a reproducer:

```
%%cython      
cdef extern from "complex.h":
       pass    
# activating code generation for complex:
cdef double complex b
```

fails with error `'error C2061: syntax error: identifier '__pyx_t_double_complex'` - the one you are seeing.

To avoid this one has to pass the define `CYTHON_CCOMPLEX=0` explicitly, in IPython this can be done via (must remember: do it only on Windows):

```
%%cython
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_CCOMPLEX=0
...
```

Now, we still have the problem, that Cython places the [complex utilities](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/1379f7aca328d4ade6cdad301e602327247612cc/Cython/Utility/Complex.c#L63) after anything we include (that means also C-verbatim-code) in the generated C-code (that is the reason `#include <complex.h>` messed up everything), thus we are left only with the forward declaration of `__pyx_t_double_complex` (this is Cython's `double complex` on the C-side) at our disposal for tricks in includes/verbatim C-code.

`_Dcomplex` has the same memory layout as `__pyx_t_double_complex`, but compiler will not perform an implicit cast.

The best I can come up with help of forward declaration of `__pyx_t_double_complex`:

```
%%cython
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_CCOMPLEX=0

# because at this point in the C-code
# we have only the forward declaration,
# pointer is all we can use:
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <complex.h> 
    struct __pyx_t_double_complex;
    inline double pyx_cabs(struct __pyx_t_double_complex *z){
        return cabs(*(_Dcomplex*)z);
    }
    """
    double pyx_cabs(double complex *z)

# here we have the whole definition 
# at our disposal, so use a wrapper
# to get read of the pointer
cdef cabs(double complex z):
    return pyx_cabs(&z)

#test that it works:
cdef double complex b
b.real = 1.0
b.imag = 2.0    
print(cabs(b))       
print(pyx_cabs(&b)) # can be used via pointer
```

So maybe it is better to wrap as follows, which has less magic (no C-verbatim),  but still needs cdef-functions for explicit casting:

```
%%cython
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_CCOMPLEX=0

cdef extern from "<complex.h>":
    ctypedef struct _Dcomplex:
        pass
    # use cname-trick to avoid name-clashes:
    double cabs_ "cabs"(_Dcomplex z)

# used for explicit casting:
cdef cabs(double complex z):
    return cabs_((<_Dcomplex*>&z)[0])

cdef double complex b
b.real = 1.0
b.imag = 2.0

print(cabs(b))
```

I didn't check whether the functions are inlined in the end-pyd-file, so that still might be an issue.

Comment: That's very useful, I suspected something was amiss with the value of `CYTHON_CCOMPLEX` here. It's not entirely clear as to how I could adapt this to work for unix too, as setting `CYTHON_CCOMPLEX=0` is obviously not something I want to just blanket add to all `.pyx` files. I imagine there's a way to pass it as an argument to `cythonize` in `setup.py` instead though, so I'll take a look.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use c code verbatim to define CYTHON_CCOMPLEX in windows branch in the pyx file.

Answer (score 1):

for those interested in changing CYTHON_CCOMPLEX t0 0 via a setup file, in the Extension you wish to build just add this line:
define_macros=[("CYTHON_CCOMPLEX", 0)] which will do the same thing in your setup file as is done by `define_macros=CYTHON_CCOMPLEX=0`.

Comment: This does not align with what OP is asking

Comment: @mishsx It does provide an alternative way of doing a key part of accepted answer, so it's at least fairly relevant.